# Mostrar la Figura "X" en una matriz, JAVA

Tags: java, matrices

Tengo que hacer una matriz con forma de X usando solo los numero 9 y 1  donde el numero 1 es el que tiene que formar la X.El usuario elige el tamaño de la matriz, tengo un poco del script donde tengo problemas en los bucles for y cuando lo corro el programa arroja los 9's y los 1's  en forma de incompleta y no se genera bien la matriz aparte de que no puedo lograr una X.

```
System.out.println("De que tamaño quiere el arreglo?.");
int cantidad = entrada.nextInt();

int[][]arreglo = new int[cantidad][cantidad];

for ( int i=0; i < arreglo.length ;i++){


    for (int j=0;  j<arreglo.length;j++){

        if((i==j)  ||  (i + j ==arreglo.length-1)){

            arreglo[i][j] = 1;
            System.out.print(arreglo[i][j] + "\t");
            System.out.println();

        }
        else{
            arreglo[i][j] = 9;
            System.out.print(arreglo[i][j] + "\t");
            System.out.println();
```

Comment: Hola Diego, bienvenido. ¿Que parte de la figura llevas? ¿En que parte del código tienes problema? Podrías darnos mas detalles, así como completar el código que proporcionaste. Saludos

Comment: Una disculpa, soy un poco nuevo en esto, ya  actualice la descripcion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con esto...

```
    System.out.println("De que tamaño quiere el arreglo?.");
    int cantidad = entrada.nextInt();

    int[][]arreglo = new int[cantidad][cantidad];

    for ( int i=0; i < arreglo.length ;i++){
          for (int j=0;  j<arreglo.length;j++){
                int x = i + 1;
                if((i==j)  ||  (j == (cantidad - x))){
                    arreglo[i][j] = 1;
                    System.out.print(arreglo[i][j] + " ");
                }
                else{
                   arreglo[i][j] = 9;
                   System.out.print(arreglo[i][j] + " ");
                }
          }  
           System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Si me funciono alberto, gracias!.

Answer (score -1):

Tu código esta bien, el detalle es que imprimes un salto de linea después de mostrar el resultado de la posición de la matriz

Comment: 1 
9 9 9 1 
9 1 
9 9 1 
9 9 1 
9 1 
9 9 9 1 
1 
9 9 9 9 1

se corrigio un poco gracias, aunque  me genero esta salida, todos los 9 del lado derecho no se estan despelgando

Comment: ocupas contar el tamaño horizontal del arreglo, y después de eso imprimir un salto de linea, me refiero a que primero imprimas una linea del arreglo y después imprimas un salto de linea y así sucesivamente